# Control Linux computer over the Internet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc, remote-control

I'm just about to set up my own home network here and I'd like to be able to control my Linux desktop over the network. VNC would be what I would normally use in this case, but the requirements are a bit different.

I basically need to be able to start work on something here on my desktop and continue that work seamlessly on a laptop or netbook as I'm moving around. I want to be able to literally pick up exactly where I left off and control my host computer's mouse pointer location, keyboard, etc and not have to open any windows: I need to be able to start from EXACTLY where I left off.

Is there any way of doing this? I'm using Ubuntu if that helps.

Comment: So why wouldn't VNC work for this?

Comment: The intent was not to create a new session like VNC typically does, but to use the existing X session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/), which exports an existing login session over VNC.

Comment: Thanks! x11vnc worked like a charm! Now I can "take" my work downstairs whenever I need to go get a snack :) Thanks a bunch, that totally solved my problem. Once I have it tunneling over SSH and running whenever my X server is, I'll be all set! Thanks, thanks, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your desktop's window manager is Compiz, [Nomad](http://old-en.opensuse.org/Nomad) makes this seamless.  Otherwise you can use a headless Xvnc running your real desktop that you connect to from both your (otherwise empty) desktop session and your laptop, or use x11vnc to export your active desktop.

You may alternately want to look into NX desktop sharing and shadow mode; see the [NX Server Administrator’s Guide](http://www.nomachine.com/documentation/html/admin-guide.html#9) and [BerliosProject:FreeNX - HowtoShadow](http://openfacts2.berlios.de/wikien/index.php/BerliosProject:FreeNX_-_HowtoShadow) for some details.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Ubuntu?